# How can I open an ASP page from HTML page?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working on an asp project, its my first time uploading it to a server (a server provided at my campus)

i will have a mix of HTML and ASP pages. I want my HTML page to be my default page, while I have links on my HTML pages pointing to asp pages.

From my local machine it worked fine (of course its local. i used the localhost:XXXX address as a link, but i know it wont work when i upload to the server). I'm using visual studio 2012.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: `<a href="whatever.asp">click here</a>`. just because it's an asp page doesn't magically make it different as far as the html is concerned.

Comment: @marc B hmm.. my links wont work.. is it because i do not have all my pages in one website folder? (i added a virtual folder in my project, but not sure if thats the same as having the actual file there)

Comment: html-in-browser only sees "url space". url space doesn't have to correspond at all with how the files which will handle the requests have to be layed out. e.g. the files' names and their locations on the server's harddrive may have absolutely no relation to what the web url you use to access them is. you'll have to figure out what your server's "layout" is.

Comment: Follow the instructions here to install ASP.NET for IIS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx You may also have to install Windows Features to enable Classic ASP hosting

Comment: Makes sense. At least I know now that a simple <a> tag will open the asp file. Thanks.

Comment: Post the html for the link that you have in your code. You might have to use relative paths. Once your site is hosted it is no longer Localhost:xxxx

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that the server you are uploading to is a *plain file server*, and **not** a *ASP server*. If that is the case, a link to a particular ASP file would simply display its *contents* and **not** the *HTML page* that is generated on your local machine by your *ASP server*.

Comment: It is a ASP server. We tried several basic asp only pages and it works fine. Thanks. I believe I'm headed in the right direction now.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to make sure you have ASP.NET Register in IIS.

link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

```
aspnet_regiis -iru
```

Run this command from both of the install folders listed below (v2 & v4)

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question completely, but...

Your IIS (web server) will have a collection of "default documents", i.e. documents it will look for if no path is provided, for example if you browse to the root of your site, such as http://tempuri.org/

What is the name of your HTML document? If it's **index.html** for example it should be loaded as the default. Some more info on default documents [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument).

Now, if you link to .html or .aspx files in your HTML doesn't matter. But if the .aspx files don't work, you should verify you have ASP.NET installed (as per answer by GlennFerrie).